# Performing action in custom Table View Cell won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom table view cell class. In the cell I have a `UIButton`. When I click on that button in the cell I want to display a popup view, in fact I'm using `RNBlurModalView`.

Because it's a `UITableViewCell`-class I can't use `self`, so I tried to create a `UIViewController` inside the custom cell, like this:

```
__weak UIViewController *ctrl;
```

And the code to display the popup like this:

```
-(IBAction)openView {
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:ctrl title:@"Title" message:@"Hello"];
    [modal show];
}
```

So instead of `initWithViewController:self` I'm trying to use `initWithViewController:ctrl`. But nothing happens when I click on the button.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The custom tableView cell is a subclass of `UIView`, and you want to show a `UIViewController` in it is not right. You have to tell the viewController which contains the current tableView to do the work for you. I will suggest you yo use delegate pattern to pass the message to viewController.
Such as:

```
cell.delegate = self; // self is the current view controller
```

implementation the delegate method

```
- (void)showTheModalView
{
   RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:ctrl title:@"Title" message:@"Hello"];
   [modal show];
}
```

and in cell implementation

```
-(IBAction)openView {
//RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:ctrl title:@"Title" message:@"Hello"];
//[modal show];
[self.delegate showTheModalView];
```

}

Declared delegate

```
@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)showTheModalView;
@end
```

Comment: It won't work, the app crashes. How should I create the delegate in my cell class? Like this? @property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;